# Configure the location for AIX core dumps

Tags: aix, core-dump

Recently I had an experience where a core dump was created in my home directory that resulted in the filesystem running out of space.

How can I tell AIX to create core dumps in some other location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page from IBM seems to have everything you'd need to know about core dump files under AIX.

- [AIX Core Dump Facility](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/KRblog/entry/aix_core_dump_facility?lang=en)

The command you're looking for looks to be `chcore`. Here's an excerpt from that page:

> A central core file repository can be set up for all accounts on the
>   system, but each account may override the default and install a custom
>   repository. Select a file system with plenty of free space for this
>   repository. All accounts will need read and write access to this
>   directory. To prevent users from deleting core files created by other
>   users, the sticky bit should be enabled. Permissions on this directory
>   should normally be 1777, the same as for `/tmp`.
>
> To set up a system-wide core file repository with unique core file
>   naming, run the following commands as root:
>
> ```
>   $ cd /path/to/filesystem
>   $ mkdir corefiles
>   $ chmod 1777
>   $ ./corefiles
>   $ chcore -p on -n on -l ./corefiles
> ```
>
> Note: Add the option -c on to turn on core file compression. The
>   settings will only be effective for newly logged in accounts and will
>   persist across reboots.
>
> To override the system-wide default repository and set up a repository
>   for a specific user, run the following commands as the user:
>
> ```
>   $ mkdir ~/corefiles
>   $ chcore -p on -n on -l ~/corefiles
> ```

Answer (score 1):

By default, core dumps will simply live in the relative path set by the core_pattern (usually this means the current working directory of the process that cores). If you prepend an absolute path to the core_pattern, then it should place the dumps there instead.

You can do this by using sysctl, or directly dumping a value into /proc

For example:

```
$ echo "/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

The cores dumps will now live in /tmp/cores/

EDIT: 
Sorry, I missed that this was for AIX. For that, you can use the chcore utility.
i.e., `chcore -p on -l /tmp/cores/`

You can also add the `-d` flag to make it the system default.

Comment: This Q is tagged AIX, aren't these how you'd do it on Linux?

Comment: I looked at the filesystem, there is no `/proc/sys/kernel` folder.

Comment: whoops, sorry. AIX uses the chcore utility. Using the same example, you can do something like:   chcore -p on -l /tmp/cores